# Does Azure Pipeline Support .NET Core 3.1.7?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is the error I get:

[image: Agent job]

This is my configuration:

[image: MSBuild Config]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of calling MSBuild latest, try to explicitly point. To MSBuild 16.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix that for the latest .NET release.
The issue can be fixed with this line of code in your pipeline (.yaml) file.

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.x'
  inputs:
    version: 6.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

Just add the above step to your YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the .NET Core SDK version to 3.x, it automatically download and install the latest in major version SDK 3.1.401, but SDK 3.1.401 is included in
Visual Studio 16.7.1. Since the hosted agent installed [Visual Studio 16.6.30320.27](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#visual-studio-enterprise-2019), which doesn't include SDK 3.1.401, you would get the error during the build.

Currently, you could set the .NET Core SDK version to **3.1.302**, or **3.1.107**, which should solve your issue.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

This issue has been reported to product team in the following case, you can follow the case to track the status:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1145815/net-coremsbuild-tooling-not-finding-right-version.html

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful for you?

Comment: Yeah, and I wrote the fix for the.NET 6 version, thanks for your awesome helpful